# Find max of specific list of columns from macro

Tags: max, stata, stata-macros

I have declared a local macro that corresponds to several variable names in my Stata project:

```
local letters a b c d
```

I want to be able to generate a new variable using all variables in the macro `letters`:

```
gen highest_letter = max(`letters')
```

However, this doesn't work, and leads to the following error message:

```
a b c d not found
```

This is because `max()` requires that the input to be separated by commas like:

```
gen highest_letter = max(a, b, c, d)
```

Is there any way for me to manipulate the macro `letters`?

Or use a function other than `max()`, such that I can find the highest value in the list of variables without manually typing them into the `max()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `egen` function `rowmax()` doesn't require commas.

```
egen highest_letter = rowmax(a b c d)
```

As above, defining a local macro here is dispensable unless you want it for some other purpose. In any case, the problem here arises regardless of whether you use a macro; the problem, as you say, is the requirement of `max()` for comma-separated arguments.

But given that you are using a macro

```
local letters : subinstr local letters " " ",", all
```

is a way to insert the commas; it will work if and only if the names are separated by single spaces. If the real list of names is very long or you are writing a program or do file, it will be quicker than inserting commas manually.